# Is there a way to force the write command to block until all bytes have been written?

Tags: pipe, file-descriptors, write

[Per the man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), the write command "writes up to count bytes" and then returns the actual number of bytes written. Thus if I wanted to ensure all bytes were written to the file descriptor, I would need to put the write within a loop and monitor that all bytes have been written.

However, is there a way to configure the file descriptor such that writes block until *all* bytes have been written?

Edit* I'm writing to pipes if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You only mention the system call, so I'm assuming you only want to have all the data passed to the operating system through the system call interface, nothing more.

> Thus if I wanted to ensure all bytes were written to the file descriptor, I would need to put the write within a loop and monitor that all bytes have been written.

Yes.

Though as far as I've tested (on Linux), in practice most writes do block until everything is written. That includes at least writes to regular files and (as far as I remember) pipes. Of course if you set the file descriptor in non-blocking mode, that might not happen (not sure if it works on regular files), and you might get a signal in the middle of the system call, interrupting it. The exact behaviours here probably depend on the system.

> However, is there a way to configure the file descriptor such that writes block until all bytes have been written?

No.

And if the system call is interrupted by a signal, and control passes back to your program, it might not even want to continue. So it's up to the application to decide if to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Use open with the O_SYNC flag.  From the Manpage:

```
       O_SYNC Write operations on the file will complete according to the  re‐
              quirements  of  synchronized  I/O  file integrity completion (by
              contrast with the synchronized  I/O  data  integrity  completion
              provided by O_DSYNC.)

              By  the  time write(2) (or similar) returns, the output data and
              associated file metadata have been transferred to the underlying
              hardware  (i.e.,  as though each write(2) was followed by a call
              to fsync(2)).  See NOTES below.
```

Or use the fsync(2) call after the write call which will flush the data explicitly.

Depending on your performance and guarantee  needs, you may prefer one way or another.

As your question is about pipes, then there is no need.  all writes go to the pipe and are considered written unless there is an error (e.g. pipe full with non blocking mode), no need for sync/direct or any flags or special calls.   If you are talking about delaying returning from write until the pipe reader has read the data, then you should examine the requirements carefully.  it is possible to craft a pipe with a limited buffer such that a write will always block until a reader accesses it, but why go through the effort to design and test such a scenario?  If you truly need feedback from the reader then maybe you should get it explicitly.  The reader could always just die right after calling the read on the pipe, so blocking the pipe to create a scheme seems worthless.

Comment: I've updated my question slightly. I'm actually using the write command against a pipe. I'm guessing I would need to use fcntl to configure the O_SYNC flag?

Comment: heh.  what do you mean be written then?   when the data is in the pipe or when the reader has read the data from the pipe?

Comment: using O_SYNC doesn mean anything for pipes.  there is no backing store to a pipe, so any such flag would be ignored.  also, fcntl cannot alter the O_SYNC status, even for normal files.

Comment: Even if the data had been written to file, using synchronous writes does not guarantee that all the bytes that were given to the write call has been written, only that those that were written were written synchronously. Right? There still has to be a loop in the user's code.

Comment: @Kusalananda my understanding is that the sync attribute is on the file descriptor so all write activity will be sync.  I know that with mmap'd files you can `msync(2)` just parts of the file, but I don't believe there's any way to mix sync with async for `write(2)`.  since writes are linear, I don't think having such a capability makes much sense.

Comment: Sure, this is what I said, all writes to disk will be synchronous. But it says nothing about actually writing all the bytes given in the write call.

Comment: @Kusalananda Okay, I understand your point.  Certainly all due care must be taken to examine the return status of the write call, and you cannot assume that if it returned without error that it wrote all the bytes, due to partial writes that may occur during interruptions.

Comment: I think this is answering another question, as the question as posted here says nothing about the underlying storage hardware, or the reader of the pipe. Only the fact that the mere `write()` system call may return without passing all the data to the kernel.